# Notepad Ctrl+N lost my document; can I recover it?

Tags: data-recovery, notepad

I wrote in Windows Notepad, hadn't saved the file yet, and accidentally hit Ctrl+N.

Notepad immediately opened to a new document, with the existing text vanishing, without asking me if I wanted to save changes.

Ctrl+Z doesn't work (because all I've got is a new, unnamed document). I do still have the window open, for whatever that's worth.

Is there any way to get my writing back?

Comment: Nope. Sorry....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No

For some reason your notepad was buggy or misbehaved, but if the file is not saved, Notepad has no type of "autosave" so you won't be able to recover this.

Normally the "CTRL + N" button will trigger a save dialog, which is weird in your situation.